# Compactness of a subset of a specific bounded $L^2$ space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

For my research, I am working with the set 
$$S =  [0,1] \times [0,\delta] \times[0,\delta^2] \times \cdots $$

where $S\subset \mathbb{R}^\infty$. I am using the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm.

I was hoping to apply Bowers Fixed point Theorem but after some thought I am starting to think this set is not compact. Am I correct that this space is not compact?

My reason from believing that the set is not compact goes as follows:

- Since the set 
  $$S_1 = [0,1]\times [0,1] \times[0,1] \times \cdots$$ 
  is not compact, it has an open cover $C$ with no finite subcover.
- Take each element of the open cover and divide the n-th component by 
  $$\frac{1}{\delta^n}$$
  to get $C'$
- Since $C'$ forms an open cover of $S$ (not entirely sure if the sets remain open), and there is no finite subcover, the set is not compact under $\|\cdot\|_2$.

If I am correct that the set is not compact, then are there any fixed point theorems that I may be able to use that many be usefull given my set and norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map you describe will not in general send open sets to open sets since the multiplication by powers of $\delta$ occurs in infinitely many coordinates simultaneously.  Your set is compact.

Comment: That's great news. Thanks.